# Proving characterisation of curvature as angular velocity of first derivative

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm working through my Differential Geometry text book and I've stumbled across a step in the proof I can't seem to understand. Suppose we have $ \alpha:G \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3 $ arc length path (so velocity is 1) which is $C^2$. We have to prove that $ \kappa(s) = \lim_{\Delta s\to\ 0} \frac{\angle\alpha'(s),\alpha '(s+\Delta s)}{|\Delta s|} $. Let's name the angle $\theta$, so $\theta = \angle\alpha'(s),\alpha '(s+\Delta s)$. In the course of the proof, the following step is left to the reader:

$ 2\sin(\theta/2) = || \alpha'(s+\Delta s) - \alpha '(s)|| $

This is supposed to be easily provable by elementary trigonometry, but I must be missing something since I can't find it.

Comment: Draw the isosceles triangle (with legs $\alpha'(s)$ and $\alpha'(s+\Delta s)$). The vertex angle is $\theta$. Now drop a perpendicular bisector from the vertex.

Comment: Solved it! Thx!